# Angular -> rendered and cloned element -> scope access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I need to be able to change variables and use methods in a scope of rendered and cloned element. How to achieve this? 
Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kashesandr/1pwzm1jb/2/

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="name">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.setName = function(name){
        $scope.name = name;
    };
}

function update() {
    var element = document.querySelector('.name')
    var scope = angular.element(element).scope()
    var copy = element.cloneNode(true)
    document.body.appendChild(copy);

    var names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
    console.log(names);

    var element1 = names[0];
    var scope1 = angular.element(element1).scope();
    scope1.$apply(function(){
        scope1.setName(123);
    });

    var element2 = names[1];
    var scope2 = angular.element(element2).scope();
    scope2.$apply(function(){
        scope2.setName(234); // this must work
    });


}   
setTimeout(update, 1500);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to do some reading on AngularJS. What you are doing is not the Angular way. You are using jQuery to get elements and manually trying to inject the scope. You are fighting against how Angular works for you!

Comment: @buzzsaw He's not using jQuery though.

Comment: @ryeballar you are quite correct, it is vanilla javascript. A cursory glance at his code was all I took to see he was fighting against Angular. Thanks for pointing out my error!

Comment: @ryeballar the way where I need to use this code is a bit unusual, needed exactly what I described above. There are some already  rendered elements and I need to duplicate some of them with small changes and with possibility to use methods variables from scope. Yes I know that it looks weird and strange... I'm experianced enough in Angular...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you are proposing, if done exactly how you are saying it must be done, is not allowed in Angular. Cloning or copying of a window or scope object is not allowed. This means that you are not able to copy `<div class="name">{{name}}</div>`, append the copy to the body, modify it, and then run a $digest cycle. This will cause an infinite loop/cyclical reference.

Please see this link for details on ng:cpws

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/cpws

If you have access to the source, which I would assume you do, you should explore updating the angular app instead of trying to modify it from the outside. What you are describing here is easily done from within the scope of the application.

Comment: sorry this is not answering my question. I need exactly what I described. Can you help me with the example above? I know that it looks strange..

Comment: does it have to be done outside of the scope of a controller? Meaning, do have have to do this in an external file not included in the angular app like a plugin or other external js file?

Comment: Yes, this should work outside of the Angular app. I just need to find a rendered element, duplicate it and make some modifications with the duplicated one (like change variable and execute `newScope.update()`)

Comment: Alright, that does make a huge difference. I will update my answer shortly.